# Is there way to detect and track the changes made to OpenLDAP

Tags: linux, centos, ldap, openldap

I'm testing some solution with OpenLDAP. I running test box with openldap server and checking functionalities, testing solution etc.

I'm wondering is there a way to track changes made to LDAP database. Some kind of changelog and if there is that kind of functionality how to enable it in Centos with OpenLDAP server 2.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is a way. You need to add the the auditlog overlay and then configure it. Below are examples of the overlay and the configuration (bottom). This will just show changes made by any user:

--SNIPPET OF cn=admin base--

# module{0}, config
dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module{0}
olcModulePath: /usr/lib64/openldap
olcModuleLoad: {0}accesslog.la
olcModuleLoad: {1}syncprov.la
olcModuleLoad: {2}back_bdb.la
olcModuleLoad: {3}auditlog.la       #THIS IS THE ONE YOU NEED

# {1}auditlog, {2}bdb, config
dn: olcOverlay={1}auditlog,olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcAuditlogConfig
olcOverlay: {1}auditlog
olcAuditlogFile: /opt/ldap/logs/auditlog.log

---------------------------------------------------

To enable via ldapmodify/add:

> ldapmodify -x -D "cn=admin,cn=config"  -W
>   dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
>   changetype: modify
>   add: olcModuleList
>   olcModuleLoad: auditlog.la
>
> ldapadd -x -D "cn=admin,cn=config"  -W
>   dn: olcOverlay={1}auditlog,olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
>   objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
>   objectClass: olcAuditlogConfig
>   olcOverlay: auditlog
>   olcAuditlogFile: /opt/ldap/logs/auditlog.log

Answer (score 1):

How about using `slapcat` to dump the database, then use some version control system like `git` to track the changes? That way you can always restore any state that you dumped with slapcat.

Comment: `slapcat` is a offline tool, so you'd really want `ldapsearch` under the `rootDN`. It's not a terrible idea if you can't add an overlay for some reason.